# .htaccess 301 with querystring and special characters

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, special-characters, query-string

I've looked around the site for answers and followed a few examples but i'm still drawing a blank with this one.
I'm trying to get the following to redirect.

**www.mydomain.com/?s=flat+roof+specifier+checklist**
to
**www.mydomain.com/resources/flat-roof-checklist/**

My rewrite rule is below.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} s=flat+roof+specifier+checklist
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /resources/flat-roof-checklist/? [L,R=301]
```

I think the issue im having is the "+" character. 
if i change my URL to:

**www.mydomain.com/?s=flat%20roof%20specifier%20checklist**

and my rewrite condition to:

**RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} s=flat%20roof%20specifier%20checklist**

It works fine.

The problem with that is, the URL HAS to be **www.mydomain.com/?s=flat+roof+specifier+checklist** (with the + characters in there) as the business has already sent out communications with that particular url, so unfortunately i can't change it.

Am i missing some sort of regx to format my url beforehand.?

There's already a 301 redirect plugin running on the site but it doesn't work with that either.
Apologies as i'm fairly new to php,wordpress,htaccess etc.

Any help will be great appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the pattern into a regex capture group and escape the plus signs, tested and working on my test server with the following

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (s=flat\+roof\+specifier\+checklist)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /resources/flat-roof-checklist/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you so very much! This has been a bit of a headache! Very very much appreciated. I had a feeling it would be a regex thing. My regex isn't too great. 

Again, thank you very much. It works a treat!

Comment: @AndyPoole No problem at all mate, have you used regexpal? It's a great site for testing regex: https://www.regexpal.com/

Comment: Nice one! I haven't used it... ...but i will be now. :)